# python datetime module and if statements

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement

I am beginner making a small project to calculate something. I need my program to use certain numbers depending on the date. I want the program to do something if the manufacturing date is between two dates. I want to know how to use the if statement with the datetime module? this is what i have so far:

```
import datetime
ManufacturingDate = input('ManufacturingDate: ')
ManufacturingDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(ManufacturingDate,"%d/%m/%Y")

if (ManufacturingDate >= datetime.date(1/1/2001) and ManufacturingDate <= datetime.date(31/1/2008)):
    #do something
```

Comment: What version of python is that?

Comment: You have not asked a question yet!

Comment: @frederick99 python 3.5

Comment: @tipanverella the question is why doesn't it work? how do i use the if statement with the datetime module in python 3.5

Answer (score 2):

You will need the two boundary dates to compare them against your input date. For that you can use `datetime.strptime` as you did with input date.

Then apply the if statement to see if your date is in the interval:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"

manufacturing_date = input('Manufacturing Date: ')
manufacturing_date = datetime.strptime(manufacturing_date,date_format)

if (datetime.strptime("1/1/2001", date_format) <= manufacturing_date < datetime.strptime("31/1/2008", date_format)):
    #do something
```

Comment: thanks very much for you answer!!

Btw you forgot to type datetime two times in the if statement. I got an error at first but when you use datetime.datetime.strptime(..............
the error is gone. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: @ghassanal-ameiry edited! If you `from datetime import datetime` you don't need to type `datetime.datetime` :) Consider marking the question as resolved

Answer (score 1):

You have a malformed "interval comparison" and wrong conversion to unix epoch time.

You need:

```
import datetime

def unix_stamp(date):
    return  datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%d/%m/%Y")

ManufacturingDate = unix_stamp(input('Manufacturing Date: '))

if unix_stamp('1/1/2001') <= ManufacturingDate <= unix_stamp('31/1/2008'):
    print 'hello world'
else:
    print 'oops'

>>>
Manufacturing Date: '1/1/1999'
oops
>>>
Manufacturing Date: '1/1/2002'
hello world
```

ETA: didn't catch datetime usage error first time around

Comment: I got this error?!

if (datetime.date(1/1/2001) <= ManufacturingDate <= datetime.date(31/1/2008)):                                                                                                                   
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Comment: ah didn't catch that first time around... see Mitjans answer for proper strptime